# How can I do site-to-site OpenVPN routing without NAT

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, nat, connection

I have two OpenVPN servers at different location.
Each machine in one location can ping and connect to every machine in the other location.

My problem is when I use SSH to connect from machine `A` in location `1` to machine `B` in location `2` and check machine `B`'s `auth.log`, I see the connection is come from the location `2` OpenVPN IP (10.0.0.2).

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssjjj.png) are my OpenVPN settings and network structure.

**Firewall rules:**
*Machine A*

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

*Machine B*

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.2
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Both OpenVPN servers have two physical interface; eth0-external & eth1-LAN, as well as OpenVPN tun0.

I think my problem is that I use NAT but I don't know how to route correctly. I need the real source machine IP.

So, in the case above, I would like to see the LAN IP (10.3.0.100) of machine `A` in machine `B`'s `auth.log` when `A` is connecting to `B`.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem and now it's work for me.
I changed the iptables rules both machine to this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: How does it solve your issue? MASQUERADE is actually one-to-many NAT...